# Bind Dynamic String to Functions Electron JS

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm building a tray menu with dynamic items, which I have done successfully. The only problem is I cannot set dynamic click events for each Item. I'm using **ShellJS** to run commands. Below is my code sample:

```
var menu = [];
for(index in file) {
    menu.push(
    {   
        label: file[index]['name'],
        click: function() 
        {
            exec('cd ' + file[index]['path'], function(code, stdout, stderr) {
                console.log('Exit code:', code);
                console.log('Program output:', stdout);
                console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
            });
        }
    }, //SampleCode
```

My Menu Items are generated successfully, only problem is with the click event it uses the last value of "file[index]['path']" lets say the last [index] value is [3] whenever there is a click event it uses the value of file[3]['path'], how do I bind the value to the function so the click event uses correct value(filePath) for that particular menu item clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I searched a lot on the internet could not find a thing, asked my friends (they helped me for hours) still, couldn't solve. Finally, I tried something and it worked.

My Updated code:

```
var menu = [];
for(index in file) {
    menu.push(
    {      
        label: file[index]['name'],
        id: box[index]['path'], //**Added id parameter**
        click: function(currentItem) {

            console.log(currentItem.id)
            // When click event is triggered it sends 
            // the current Menu Item as Object
            // From that object I can access the 'id' 
            // example: currentItem.label will give the current items label.
        }
    }, //Sample Code
```